# How to create LUIS application that can be accessed through my organization account?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-billing-api

I am using LUIS to extract intent for the user utterances. I have did it through my own free Microsoft account. Now how can I get a organization subscription? Is it free like the normal Microsoft account or billing different for the organization or enterprise accounts.

The documentation was not clear about the billing. Also I am new to Azure.

[image]

Comment: LUIS doesn't care - generally - what type of account you have -- as long as you have a valid key. What kind of organization account are you wanting to create or join?

Comment: Yes, LUIS doesn't care. But  my organization cares and scared to grant any permission to access resources in the organization. Is there any security will be breached or any harm to my organization's security by granting this consent to access organization resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something you are doing for your own business, then you can convert your free account to a Pay-As-You-Go account. Instructions are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-upgrade-azure-subscription)

If you are doing this for your employer then they would need to provide the subscription information to you and grant you contributor access.

The image in your question isn't really related to subscriptions or billing. Did you intend to include it? What the image is talking about is the active directory consent. Basically, your Luis app needs certain AD permission to do stuff, and only someone logged in with the correct privileges and 'consent' to granted them. The consent framework is a pretty large and important topic. Here is a great place to [get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-consent-framework).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am doing for my employer. But all I can do is to make them understand completely what LUIS is and what type of consent LUIS needs to access the organization resources. Because they want to do everything from their side after proper understandings and finally they give me ID and KEY for luis and contributor rights to train it.

Comment: Now to be brief, they are afraid of the security breach to grant the consent/access. And even I don't have proper answers to them, since I am new to Azure, LUIS, BOT framework and all.. I have managed to develop a bot, but I am now stuck to take this to my organization and convince them to bring it live.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are looking for. All this is asking is that the Luis.ai application be granted access to your active directory. Specifically, it wants the following permissions: 1. View Users Email Address, 2. Sign Users In, 3. View Users Basic Profile, 4. Sign In and Read User Profile.    These are pretty standard consent requests for application type service principals. It's important to remember that you aren't granting PEOPLE this access, you are granting the application access. LUIS is a fully security compliant Microsoft product, not some unknown tool with questionable origins

Comment: Here is the AAD doc for LUIS. Let me know what questions it doesn't answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-collaborate#azure-active-directory-tenant-user